# Get index of the polygon that a particular tessface belongs to

Tags: python, scripting

I can do this to print the indices of all the (tessellated) triangles in a mesh:

```
ob = bpy.context.active_object
me = ob.data
me.calc_tessface()
for f in me.tessfaces:
    print(f.index)
```

Also, if I want the indices of all the polygons, I could do:

```
for f in me.polygons:
    print(f.index)
```

However, is there a way to figure out which polygon does a triangle belongs to? Alternatively, is it possible to iterate over all the tessfaces belonging to a polygon?